# C# JSON Custom Result List Name

Tags: c#, json, wcf

How can I override C#'s JSON response from **<MethodName>Results** to the class name?

It always returns the methodname+Results.  Is there a way for me to change it to the classname instead?

Or am I doing something wrong on my code?

Here's my Exchange_Reason class

```
[DataContract]
public class Exchange_Reason
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Exchange_Reason_ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Reason { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

My Service Contract

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "getExchange_Reason_List")]
    List<Exchange_Reason> GetExchange_Reason_List();
```

The implementation

```
public List<Exchange_Reason> GetExchange_Reason_List()
{
     List<Exchange_Reason> results = new List<Exchange_Reason>();
     ...
     while (reader.Read())
     {
           results.Add(new Exchange_Reason()
           {
                 Exchange_Reason_ID = reader["Exchange_Reason_ID"].ToString(),
                 Reason = reader["Reason"].ToString(),
                 Status = reader["Status"].ToString()
           });
     }
     return results;
}
```

And the results

```
{
    GetExchange_Reason_ListResult: [
        {
            Exchange_Reason_ID: "1000001",
            Reason: "Rotten",
            Status: "Active"
        },
        {
            Exchange_Reason_ID: "1000002",
            Reason: "Expired",
            Status: "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

I need it to be:

```
{
    Exchange_Reasons: [
        {
            Exchange_Reason_ID: "1000001",
            Reason: "Rotten",
            Status: "Active"
        },
        {
            Exchange_Reason_ID: "1000002",
            Reason: "Expired",
            Status: "Active"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

that because your `BodyStyle` is wrapped. at first remove `BodyStyle` from your `WebInvoke` then wrap your output the way you want. i assume you want this:

```
 [DataContract]
public class GetExchange_Reason_ListResult
{
    [DataMember]
    public Exchange_Reason[] Exchange_Reasons { get; set; }
}

public class Exchange_Reason
{
    public string Exchange_Reason_ID { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

your method should be like this:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "getExchange_Reason_List")]
GetExchange_Reason_ListResult GetExchange_Reason_List();
```